# Is it possible to install Windows 10 IoT on Banana Pi?

Tags: windows-10-iot-core, banana-pi

Many devices/platforms are supported by Microsoft. The Banana Pi isn't listed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/hardware/dn914597%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). But the specifications of the Banana Pi (first generation in this case) are quite similar to that of Raspbian Pi:

```
╔═════╦═════════════════════════════╦════════════════════════════════╗
║     ║      Raspberry Pi 2 B       ║         Banana Pi (1)          ║
╠═════╬═════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════╣
║ SOC ║ Broadcom BCM2836            ║ Allwinner A20                  ║
║ CPU ║ ARM Cortex-A7 1GHz Dualcore ║ ARM Cortex-A7 900 MHz Quadcore ║
║ GPU ║ Broadcom VideoCore IV       ║ Mali400MP2 GPU                 ║
║ RAM ║ 1024 DDR2 RAM               ║ 1024 DDR3 RAM                  ║
║ LAN ║ 10/100-MBit-Ethernet        ║ 10/100/1000-Mbit/s-Ethernet    ║
╚═════╩═════════════════════════════╩════════════════════════════════╝
```

> Source:
>   http://jankarres.de/2015/03/raspberry-pi-2-performance-vergleich-und-benchmarks/

**My Question**: Is is possible to get Windows 10 IoT running on a Banana Pi (not only theoretically)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is now possible (officially) to run Windows 10 IoT Core on the newer Banana Pi (Allwinner Technology Banana Pi BPI-M64, Allwinner Technology Pine64) Boards:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/blob/master/doc/get_started/windows10-iot-core-banana-pi-bpi-m64-csharp.md

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/iot-hub-tested-configurations/#certified-for-iot-devices

And maybe useful for a custom try: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn916104%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 1):

As of today, only 3 devices are supported by Windows 10 IoT Core.

- Raspberry Pi 2
- MinnowBoard Max
- DragonBoard410c

Check the details here http://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/GetStarted.htm

Comment: Did your question get answered?

Comment: Sorry for my very late reply. "Not Supported" doesn't mean that it's not possible, right?

Answer (score 0):

As of date of this posting MS specifically list Banana Pi M64   Allwinner A64 as a ["Community Device"](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/explore/deviceoptions)

Answer (score 0):

Allwinner-Banana-Pi-BPI-M64 is listed in Windows 10 compatibility list in the URL https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/getstarted/prototype/selectdevice
You got to wait until the page list (big list) loads and in almost last row this is listed.
I'm working on loading Win IoT core onto M64 board.  If successful i shall put my report here.